# Bundle a page with custom url and a function

Tags: pages, archives

I have a plugin that allows users to bookmark posts and I want to create a page/archive/index for all those bookmarked posts. What I've done so far is: created a menu link that is displayed if user has bookmarked posts, added a button to bookmark posts and wrote a loop that will display those bookmarked posts based on the post id.

I have an idea on how to make this possible. I want to include a page `mywpblog.com/bookmarked/` *(bundled into the theme)* - that will be based on archive.php code, that will act like an archive page and a function that would determine if this is the `.../bookmarked/` page like `is_bookmarked_page();`.

[TL;DR] How to include a page with the theme (ex. ...`/bookmarked/`) and a function to distinguish that page?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new file and include a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) to structure the loop and display your bookmarks.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Bookmarked Page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
```

Then just make sure a page exists called **bookmarked** (so the url is in place) and set it's template to the custom page template you created.

[image]

You can also write a template to target a [specific page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page).

1. page-{slug}.php
2. page-{ID}.php

---

`is_bookmarked_page()` isn't really required because you will already know your template is being used. There are however [page template functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#page-template-functions) that could help.

- [`get_page_template ()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template/)
- [`wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_theme/get_page_templates/)
- [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/)
- [`get_page_template_slug()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/)

---

It's also possible to construct this page automatically [after_switch_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme) by creating the page using [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) and setting the template with [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).

Create the page if it doesn't already exist:

```
$title = __( 'Bookmarks' );
if ( NULL == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'post_name'      => 'bookmarked',
            'post_title'     => $title,
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status'    => 'closed',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
        )
    );
}
```

Set the page template:

```
$template_full_path = trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . $template_rel_path;

if ( file_exists( $template_full_path ) ) {

    // set the post meta data -- use relative path
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', $template_rel_path );
}
```

Comment: Super helpful! One question. Could you explain the 'setting page template' part? Btw. I'm using `is_page( $post_id );` to differentiate the page.

Comment: The setting page template part shows up when you edit a page. You'll see the box when you have templates available. Just make sure you have the Page Attributes meta box enabled.

Comment: I meant programmatically setting page template, not in the admin menu on the backend. I'd like to know what part does what in the code snippet you provided me with, thank you!

Comment: `_wp_page_template` is the meta key where the path to the template is stored on the post. The code above just checks to make sure the file exists before setting it using `update_post_meta`. The path should be relative to your theme directory which is why it's called `$template_rel_path`. For example; `'templates/my-page-template.php'`.

Comment: Ahhhh it was the `_wp_page_template` part I wasn't sure about, thanks for explaining and pointing me in the right direction! Thanks again, I appreciate your help!